# Why can we take the logarithm (or exponentiate) both sides of an equation?

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, logarithms, exponential-function

I feel I would want to make this sort of argument:

$$\lim_{x \to a} \log(f(x)) =  \log(\lim_{x \to a}f(x)) = \log(f(a))$$

so that we require both

1) $\log$ to be continuous at $f(a)$,

and

2) $f$ to be continuous at $x=a$

Is this true?

If so, this seems a bit too technical to teach my class of students in Calculus I -- it seems more appropriate of a topic for introductory analysis / advanced calculus.  So I am looking for a more hand-wavy discussion to let the curious students know why it is that we can take the log (or exponentiate) each side of an equation.

Thanks,

Comment: It seems to me that (1) and (2) could be viewed as "continuity definition", so you might want to approach from there, assuming students have seen the definition of continuity.

Comment: I am confused about your question.  As two sides of an equation are equal we can do *anything* that is well defined to both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I see why continuity would come into it at all. You can take the log of both sides because log is a well-defined function, i.e. if $a = b$ then $f(a) = f(b)$.

To show why taking the log of both sides is useful, you'd want to argue that the solutions of $f(a) = f(b)$ correspond to the solutions of $a = b$ (for those solutions in the appropriate domain).

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that continuity of real functions is an essential topic in a calculus class. How would you state the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus without mentioning continuity? All you need here is that a composite $gf$ of  continuous functions $g, f$ is continuous, and that continuity of a  function $h(x)$ at $x=a$  can be $defined$ as $\lim_{x\to a} h(x)=h(a).$

Comment: that requires the students to understand that $f$ must be continuous, $g = log$ must be continuous, and then the composition is continuous, which I think would go over their heads and seems more of a topic in continuity meant for advanced calculus / introductory analysis students ...

Comment: It may go over their heads but it's *essential* that they learn it and not fall for the pitfalls and this is *exactly* the time the pitfalls show up and we *need* to nip them early.  If kids don't learn continuity in calculus class, they'll learn it on the streets.  And no-one wants that.

Comment: Couldn't agree more with @fleablood comments. As an educator one must educate the students honestly. This includes avoiding any hand waving and presenting the correct stuff. If one assumes that students can't deal with proper proofs then avoid the proof, but don't replace proof with hand waving. Often an informal discussion of the key ideas in a proof are well understood by students. It is the formal presentation which they have trouble with.